# store CCLabelTTF color in GameConfig.h

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, label

How can I store CCLabelTTF color in GameConfig.h like:

```
#define kGameLabelColor ccc3(79,71,59);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define it in GameConfig.h, without the `;` in the end:

```
#define kGameLabelColor ccc3(79,71,59)
```

To use it:

```
#import "GameConfig.h"

...

[label setColor:kGameLabelColor];
```

If you want to change the color of all your labels in the whole app by default, I think you may consider modifying `initWithString` method in CCLabelTTF.m, adding `color_ = ccc3(79,71,59);`.

Comment: can you explain me once again, i'll try declare #define kLabelFontName ICE_AGE.ttf but the kLabelFontName visible as ICE_AGE without .ttf

Comment: I don't quite understand your requirements... Try `#define kLabelFontName @"ICE_AGE.ttf"` and in your `initWithString` or `labelWithString` set `fontName` to `kLabelFontName`. Ensure that you have added "ICE_AGE.ttf" into your project as resource.

Comment: CCLabelTTF class is not available in android?